# Google Map MyCurrentLocation is not Working

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-location, currentlocation

I am working with the android emulator,
Once I run the app, 
It centers in the right longitude and latitude,
but the blue dot is not in there to indicate my current location.

```
   @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mGoogleMap) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Navi.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Navi.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            this.gMap = mGoogleMap;
            if (lat != 0.0 & lng != 0.0) {
                if (this.gMap != null) {
                    this.gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    this.gMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                    this.gMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                    this.gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                    this.gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat, lng)));
                    this.gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14f));
                }
            } else {
                if (this.gMap != null) {
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(14.6760, 121.0437);
                    this.gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                    this.gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14f));
                }
            }
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Navi.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

But once I received my new Longitude and latitude,
The blue dot appears.

```
 private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            lat = arg1.getDoubleExtra("lat", 0);
            lng = arg1.getDoubleExtra("long", 0);
            if (lat != 0.0 & lng != 0.0) {
                if (gMap != null) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Navi.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Navi.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                        gMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                        gMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                        gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                        gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat, lng)));
                        gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14f));
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.e("LAT", "" + lat);
            Log.e("LNG", "" + lng);
        }

    }
```

What's the cause of this problem?

Comment: try in a real device too

Comment: Okay I will. Thanks